# Multiple targets per-entry in Webpack 4

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Is it possible to define a different `target` per-entry, for both webpack and webpack-dev-server?

I tried following some guides which had different configurations passed to `module.exports`, but using webpack 4 it seems to not like getting an array (also - I'm not sure if this is really what I'd want, since it may conflict with webpack-dev-server).

Use-case is loading a wasm file in a web-worker, which is currently problematic, so I'd rather load the worker manually. However the worker is not only a shim for loading the wasm file, it also imports other js files and should be bundled via webpack.

Specifying only separate entries, without the `target` setting, doesn't seem to work either (I assume because bundles created this way assume the existence of document, window, etc.)

Comment: No, there is not possible to define target per entry: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/schemas/WebpackOptions.json#L2102-L2121